# Performance-impact of empty Page_Load() methods

Tags: asp.net, performance, webforms

When adding a new page or user control to an ASP.NET webforms application, the code-behind class contains an empty Page_Load() event handler:

```
public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

I have an existing web app, where many pages and controls still contain these empty event handlers (they are not used).

**Question:** Is there any performance impact due to these empty event handlers and should they therefore be removed from all pages and controls?

**Please note:** I'm not mainly (or not only) concerned about any runtime-overhead, due to the empty event handler being called. I also wonder about any overhead while the page (markup) is JIT-compiled (because the event handlers have to be wired up to the events - probably using some reflection code).

**Update**: there was no real answer so far, so I can't accept any of them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the performance cost of autoeventwireup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257112/what-is-the-performance-cost-of-autoeventwireup)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`AutoEventWireup` is not done at the compile time. When it set to `true`, the runtime has to look for each of the page event handlers using `Delegate.CreateDelegate` method for this. Here is a great article which describes this behaviour: [Inside AutoEventWireup](https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2006/02/16/inside-autoeventwireup.aspx).

There is a similar question here: [What is the performance cost of autoeventwireup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257112/)

Answer (score 2):

While the stack frame must be adjusted to enter and leave your method (and doing nothing) as opposed to simply calling the base implementation (in this case `System.Web.UI.Page`
), the performance impact is incredibly small and most likely unmeasurable so you should be fine.

Comment: There is no base implementation, since Page_Load is an event handler and not an override of a virtual method! The event handler has to be wired up to the Load-event at runtime.

Comment: By base implementation I refer to the internal Page methods that trigger the delegate, I apologize if it was misleading or if it implies inheritance to some. The concept is the same however since the stack frame will be adjusted. Also, a common approach in many .NET shops is to create a class that inherits from Page that acts as a base implementation that an application's pages inherit from.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly certain Page_Load occurs whether it's there or not.  Much like PreRender occurs, or Page_Init.

Removing it will do nothing for performance.

Comment: What do you mean with "Page_Load occurs"? Can you elaborate? PreRender or OnLoad are overridden virtual methods, while Page_Load and Page_Init are event handlers. I don't think they can be compared.

Comment: Well what I mean by that is, doesn't Page_Load get called whether or not you actually define the method?  PreRender happens even if you don't define the method.