# Sub Page_Init method: Event init cannot be found

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, events, init

The following method is return an error:  'Event init cannot be found' and get error on System.Web.UI.Page

Visual Studio 2010, framework 3.5

```
Public Class_default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Private Sub Page_Init(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Init

End Sub
```

Comment: Does the class inherit from `System.Web.UI.Page`?

Comment: Then you have the answer. `MyBase` addresses your base class(if you don't have a base class it's `Object`). If that base class does not have this event you're getting this compiler error.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0hds5k93(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I added the following but I get an error on System.Web.UI.Page:   Public Class _default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Comment: Did you changed your method from `private` to `protected`?

Comment: When you say " I get an error on System.Web.UI.Page ..." is that the same "Event init cannot be found error"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not VB.NET expert (I am writing on C#) but i can say that the cause of the problem is that you need to override **OnInit** method instead of Page_Init.

So, you need to use the following code:

```
Public Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub

    Protected Friend Overrides Sub OnInit(ByVal e As EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnInit(e)
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: methods with name `Page_{eventName}` should be executed automatically. There is no need to add override.

Answer (score 1):

I think Maxim is correct, however you can also add your event handler by doing:

```
AddHandler Me.Init, AddressOf Page_Init
```

I think that's right, sorry my VB is pretty rusty.

Answer (score 1):

Well,

I assume you are using [`AutoEventWireup="true"`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680878/what-does-autoeventwireup-page-property-mean) in your markup but you have also marked your handler with the `Handles` keyword.

AutoEventWireup won't work, its not able to access private members of your class directly.

Set `AutoEventWireup="false"` and save its [needless performance penalty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257112/autoeventwireup-performance-cost), the handler should still fire because it explicitly `Handles` the `Page.Init` event.

Since you're handling the event explicitly you are also free to change the name of the event handler and remove the ugly `_`.

Answer (score 0):

The majority of your Crystal Reports code is likely in the Page_Load event. If you move it to the Page_Init you'll find it works correctly.